# I want to use DropDownListFor to edit the ingredients that my recipe has, so I need to map an ICollection item to DropDownListFor

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am using EF and my relationship between tables is many-to-many. I want to display and edit the ICollection property to not only display my ingredients from a recipe, but to also edit, add, or delete them.

I tried to use EditorFor, but the changes of the ingredient were never changed and submitted to the database. I want to use DropDownList because it can show the ingredients that my recipe has in a list format so I can choose between them.

> This is my Recipe and Ingredients Model with the relational table RecipesIngredients:

```html
namespace Licenta.Models
{
    public class Recipe
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDRecipe { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Desc { get; set; }
        public string Steps { get; set; }
        public float Kcal { get; set; }
        public float Pro { get; set; }
        public float Carbo { get; set; }
        public float Fat { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RecipesIngredients> RecipesIngredients { get; set; }

    }
}

namespace Licenta.Models
{
    public class RecipesIngredients
    {
        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 1)]
        public int IDRecipe { get; set; }

        [Key]
        [Column(Order = 2)]
        public int IDIngredient { get; set; }

        public virtual Recipe Recipe { get; set; }
        public virtual Ingredient Ingredient { get; set; }
    }
}

namespace Licenta.Models
{
    public class Ingredient
    {
        [Key]
        public int IDIngredient { get; set; }
        public string Nume { get; set; }
        public float Kcal { get; set; }
        public float Pro { get; set; }
        public float Carbo { get; set; }
        public float Fat { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<RecipesIngredients> RecipesIngredients { get; set; }
    }
}
```

> This is my Controller:

```html
public ActionResult Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Recipe recipe = db.Recipes.Find(id);
            if (recipe == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(recipe);
        }

        // POST: Recipes/Edit/5
        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Edit([Bind(Include = "IDRecipe,Name,Kcal,Pro,Carbo,Fat,Desc,Steps,Ingredients,RecipesIngredients")] Recipe recipe)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(recipe).State = EntityState.Modified;
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(recipe);
        }
```

> And the View of the Edit page:

```html
@model Licenta.Models.Recipe

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Edit";
}

<h2>Edit</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    
    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Rețetă</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.IDRecipe)

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Name, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Name, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Name, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        

        
        <div class="form-group">
            @foreach (var item in Model.RecipesIngredients)
                {
                    <td>
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => item.Ingredient.Nume, @* this is where i want to edit the ingredients*@)
                    </td>
                }
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.RecipesIngredients, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

That is the View that I want to use to edit my ingredients. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Are you wanting to edit directly in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes. I want to edit the ingredients from this Recipe View

Comment: I'm pretty sure you will need a third party tool to accomplish this.  Maybe Kendo, or jquery UI combo box.  The MVC select list is just a display list, not editable.  Personally, I would list my recipes in a table instead of a ddl, with an edit button next to each that triggers an edit form in a modal.